# Listing first name, last name at Users listing page

Tags: users

I have installed and configured User Profile module, which allows me to add fields like First Name, Last Name for users.

As of now, when I go to users list at /admin/user/user I see username column. How can I can add these extra fields in the column?

Comment: Are you using Drupal 7 and profile 2 module ?

Comment: Are you want to add fields without using profile module..?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [Administration views module](https://drupal.org/project/admin_views) which will replace all administration overviews, e.g. the list of users, with actual views. You will then be able to add any field you have attached to user profiles to your overview as well. This will work for both Drupal 6 and 7.

Comment: Admin Views is definitely the best way to go for this. Not only do you get your fields but you get all the power of expressed filters and views bulk operations too. Win win win.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add fields in profile.

You have to create profile type and add fields at admin/structure/profile path.

Comment: my answer is applicable only if you are using drupal7 and profile 2 module.

Comment: but how to add those field to /admin/user/user link.could you please explain more ..thanks

Comment: Is there any specific requirements to all the field at admin/user/user url? As it is coming from drupal core user module

Comment: I have created a content type form from the profiles module for anonymous user.On anonymous user registration a node is created It contains First name and Last Name and many more fields.But i want is that when admin creates account from this path "admin/user/user" there i want to add the first name and last Name and on submit also a node is created in content_type_profile table

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change in your administrative view then all hooks are available here for content modification of admin user..
[Content administration and module settings UI.](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.admin.inc/7)

i hope this helps you..